# If you make a shehakol on water at a restaurant before the meat is served do you say another shehakol on the meat?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

If you make a shehakol on water at a restaurant before the meat is served do you say another shehakol on the meat?

If you had the meat in mind?
If you didn't have the meat in mind?
Does the fact that the water is a liquid and the meat being a solid have any significance?

Do the laws of a guest saying one bracha on everything of the same type  that is served henceforth apply here?

Comment: I can't answer all of your questions, but I'm pretty sure the answer to your last one is "no." My understanding of that rule is that it applies because the guest doesn't know what food will be brought out. That's not the case in a restaurant where you order exactly what you want to eat.

Comment: @Daniel, I was thinking the same thing, but do you have a source? What about asking your host for stuff? Does the moment you ask make the guest rule *batel*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be covered in  [סימן נז - דין ברך על מאכל או משקה, ואחר כך הביאו לו עוד](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0056_L2)  in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch:

> **סעיף ה'**: בֵּרַךְ עַל הַשֵּׁכָר וְנִתְכַּוֵּן לִפְטוֹר כָּל מַה שֶּׁיָּבִיאוּ לוֹ מִבִּרְכַּת שֶׁהַכֹּל, וְהֵבִיאוּ לוֹ דָּגִים, אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ עַל הַדָּגִים. אֲבָל אִם הָיְתָה דַּעְתּוֹ סְתָם, אֲפִלּוּ אִם בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁהֵבִיאוּ לוֹ אֶת הַדָּגִים עֲדַיִן הָיָה שֵׁכָר לְפָנָיו, מִכָּל מָקוֹם צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ עַל הַדָּגִים. וְלֹא דָּמִי לְפֵּרוֹת, אֲפִלּוּ שֶׁאֵלוּ תַּפּוּחִים וְאֵלּוּ אֱגוֹזִים, מִכָּל מָקוֹם הַכֹּל מִין אֹכֶל הוּא. אֲבָל שֵׁכָר וְדָגִים הֵמָּה לְגַמְרֵי שְׁנֵי מִינִים מְחֻלָּקִים. זֶה אֹכֶל וְזֶה מַשְׁקֶה, וְאֵינָן פּוֹטְרִין זֶה אֶת זֶה, אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן הָיו לְפָנָיו בִּשְׁעַת בְּרָכָה, אוֹ שֶׁהָיְתָה דַּעְתּוֹ עֲלֵיהֶם ([סִימָן ר"ו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_17.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2)). ‏

- If you make Shehakol on a liquid and have explicit intent to cover everything Shehakol that will arrive during the meal, then you don't make another Bracha.
- If you didn't think about it, then you have to make another Bracha on solids.

  - Unlike other cases where the rules are more complex. This is because  food and drink are so dissimilar, that without explicit intent you have to make another Bracha.

Comment: If you ordered chicken and have the water in front of you. If you didn't have in mind the chicken, when making the blessing, but knew that it was coming, is that the same as "having in mind"?

Comment: נִתְכַּוֵּן לִפְטוֹר כָּל מַה שֶּׁיָּבִיאוּ לוֹ  means _you have intention to cover all Shehakols that will be served during this meal_.

Comment: BTW this is "Shaycher" beer, but with water there isanother factor -- that if one is not thirsty, the brocho is levatalah, and so if one would make a shahakol on water, when one is not really thirsty, then not only will th ebrocho not cover the meat, but it was even a brocho levatal for the water itself